# Regarding Enderton’s group axioms

Tags: group-theory, first-order-logic

In his *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* Enderton writes on page 93 (2nd edition): “… The class of all groups is an elementary class, being the class of all models of the conjunction of the group axioms:

∀ x ∀ y ∀ z (x ◦ y) ◦ z = x ◦ (y ◦ z);
∀ x ∀ y ∃ z x ◦ z = y;
∀ x ∀ y ∃ z z ◦ x = y.”

I can’t deduce the existence of unique identity element from the above axioms. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just play with the axioms.  For example, the existence of a left identity follows from:  Fix $x\in G$ and choose $z$ with $zx=x$.  We contend that $zg=g$ for all $g\in G$.  So, choose $g\in G$.  Then choose $y$ such that $xy=g$  Now remark that $zg=z(xy)=(zx)y=xy=g$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely trivial. The two latter axioms include the existence of a right and left identity for each element $x$, if we take $y=x$. Then they read as

$$\forall x\exists e_l:e_lx=x,\\
\forall x\exists e_r:xe_r=x.$$

We can now prove that both are independent of $x$ in the sense that if $e_r$ is a right identity for $x$, it is a right identity for all group elements. Because for all $x$ and $y$ there is a $z$ such that $y=zx$. But then $ye_r=(zx)e_r=z(xe_r)=zx=y$. A similar argument works for the left identity.

Now we can show that every right identity is a left identity and vice versa, and that they are unique. The first statement is true because $e_l=e_le_r=e_r$ for any right identity $e_r$ and left identity $e_l$. For uniqueness consider two identities $e$ and $\tilde e$. Then $\tilde e=e\tilde e=e$, so the identity is unique.